Spring cloud gateway - Filter arguments not updated with refresh or gateway refresh endpoints
We using custom gateway filter for spring cloud gateway. The configuration looks like below:
Filter class:
@Component
public class CustomFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<CustomFilter.Config> {

    public static class Config {
        private String type;
        private LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> values;
        //Getters & Setters
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            //some filter function
        };
    }
}

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: my-service
          uri: https://myservice.host.com
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/{version}/api-name
          filters:
            - name: CustomFilter
              args:
                type: type1
                values:
                  key1: value1

We want to add additional key value pair under values, like:
                values:
                  key1: value1
                  key2: value2

I want to add additional key value pair and update configuration dynamically. I tried both /actuator/refresh and /actuator/gateway/refresh to update configuration but neither of them worked. Can someone help on how to update these values dynamically?

Option 1: change properties programatically
You can access properties in runtime, change them and publish RefreshRoutesEvent to make Gateway reload properties set in CachingRouteLocator
@Autowired GatewayProperties gatewayProperties;
@Autowired ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

public void someMethod() {
    List<FilterDefinition> filters = this.gatewayProperties.getRoutes().get(0).getFilters();
    // update filters however
    
    // this will make RouteLocator reload properties
    this.eventPublisher.publishEvent(new RefreshRoutesEvent(this));
}


Option 2: reload properties file and recreate beans
If you definetely want to do it in yaml it will be harder, since reading of the properties / yaml files is done once at startup. You can create a scheduler to reload the properties as shown here but you still need to figure out the way to make GatewayProperties to reread / rebind values and still will endup having to trigger the RefreshRoutesEvent.

Option 3: Implement your own RouteLocator
An alternative solution could be to provide your own solution of RouteLocator and make it reread properties each time
